# Users,Roles and permissions in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, microservices

I want to register users. Now each user has 2 different roles- Role1 and Role2. Role1 can access some APIs. Role 2 can access some other APIs. I have to implement this using microservices. `Can my microservices be these-`

1. Register microservice (To register all kinds of users)
2. Authentication and authorization microservice (that authenticates the users as valid or invalid and authorizes them based on the roles)
3. Role1 microservice(with all its controller methods)
4. Role2 microservice(with all its controller methods)
   Now Authentication microservice would need the registration details to authenticate the user so `can that be done using open feign client`

`also is it possible to have a separate service for each role and secure the APIs based on roles with authentication and authorization as a separate microservice? If no then what can be an alternate solution`

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to have a separate service for each role?

Ideally, you shouldn't create the microservices based upon the role. Introduction of more roles & you will end up with as many as services.

> Can my microservices be these-
>
> Register microservice (To register all kinds of users)
>
> Authentication and authorization microservice (that authenticates the
> users as valid or invalid and authorizes them based on the roles)
>
> Role1 microservice(with all its controller methods)
>
> Role2 microservice(with all its controller methods)

There're many ways to fulfill the requirements while keeping the design principles intact. One such way, you can go with `auth-service`, `user-service` and `third-service` (say).

**auth-service:** This service will perform authentication & authorization by verifying the user details. This service can also held some minimalistic data to validate the user identity and therefore, it don't need to rely on *user-service* during the login process. Your *auth-service* issue some sort of token once user get verified. The token could be an `opaque token` or `JWT`. If  your *auth-service* can issue JWT containing the role details then even your third-service don't need to rely on auth-service.

**user-service:** This service will contain all the user information and your *third-service* can talk to it to get some details while performing its operations.

**third-service:** This service will act as `resource-server` having the protected resources available to different roles. If the token is JWT, this service will verifying the token and get the details from it. In case of opaque token this service need to talk with auth-service to verify the token and get the role details. Once you've the role details, you can write some validation code in the controller to check the access based up on the role and take a decision to allow or deny further access.